EME on 13cm, which polarization?
If I u understand correctly for 13cm eme one should TX (to the moon) using RHCP and the moon will reflect a LHCP signal as the polarization is mirrored on reflections.
If this is correct, how would a feed for a parabolic antenna look like?
I assume it needs to be some sort of combined feed where polarization can be switched, correct?

This is a good site for Q&A and there are lots of experts present, but for EME I recommend binge-reading all of the extensive material already written about it. (I do this from time to time myself, thinking maybe this will be the decade that I finally build an EME station). A quick search will find tens of wonderful old-school sites covering all aspects of it. Things like this feed polarisation question are reasonable starting questions but they are well covered elsewhere. So I suggest reading everything, twice, and then asking here about specific problems, or novel ideas you have.

I'm only asking here what I don't find an answer to after extensive searching, it you know a link which is useful I'm happy use it

E.g. I've fully read this article before asking but even when covered at the end I didn't find the answer I was looking for https://wiki.microwavers.org.uk/Microwave_EME#Introduction

From the answer below I've learned that I need a septum feed

I'm not a microwave guy, but my understanding is that when you use waveguide for a feed, you can accomplish this using a septum polarizer.
Basically, the polarizer has two "input" ports and one "output" port. The linear mode of one input port couples to the RHCP mode of the output port (so you attach your transmitter to that one), and the other input port couples to the LHCP mode of the output port (so you use that one for your receiver). Then you attach whatever horn you need to the output port, and point it at your dish.

There are several ways to alternate polarization.
You could use an elliptical dish (two feed points) with two helical antennas of opposite polarization.
Some patch antennas can reverse polarization by choosing a different feed point on the same antenna.
You could use crossed yagi antennas with a reversible phasing harness (basically two feed points into the same phasing harness), although feeding dishes with something as large as a yagi is rare.
I hadn't heard of the septum polarizer mentioned in the other answer, but that would work well for horn feeds.

In the meanwhile I've found what I need, the CIR2340 https://rfhamdesign.com/products/dish-feeds/septum-dish-feed/index.php
